# Counting the 1's and 2's in a Table

Tags: sql

I have this table

```
SECTION
```

Which consist of field called

```
Semester 
2
1
1
1
2
1
1
2
2
2
1
2
```

I need sql to  count how many 1's and how many 2's are there

And out put like this

```
semester 1  |  semester 2
6           |   6
```

Comment: Rename the question...

Comment: Also pivot if you want it in that format

Comment: have you tried anything? There are some simple ways to achieve this

Answer (score 3):

[Demo here](https://data.stackexchange.com/stackoverflow/query/524701):After testing

```
select 
sum(Case when semester=1 then 1 else 0 end) as 'Semester1',
sum(Case when semester=2 then 1 else 0 end) as 'Semester2'
from section
```

Comment: grouping data by semester will create multiple records for each semester and that will not match with OP's output.

Comment: This is what I was looking for bt  not exactly

Comment: Select sum (case when semester = 1 then 1 end)"semester 1" ,sum (case when semester = 2 then 1 end) "semester 2" from section ;

Comment: @BradleyLucas:I have used some dummy tablename,updated as per your table name

Answer (score 2):

Try out this:

```
Select sum(case when semster =1 then 1 else 0 end) as semster1 ,
       sum(case when semster =2 then 1 else 0 end) as semster2  
from section;
```

Answer (score -1):

Assuming there are more values than 1 and 2, and that the values are integers:

```
SELECT semester, count(*)
FROM section
WHERE semester = 1 OR semester = 2
GROUP BY semester
```

Comment: What is the use of `WHERE semester = 1 OR semester = 2` ?

Comment: OP said he just wants to count the 1's and 2's. As there are no details, I assume there can be different number besides 1 and 2...

Comment: What did you get? I made a simple test and got the correct result... (Assuming the values are integers, not varchars).